# Handling mass amount of Text Boxes

Tags: c#, textbox

So I have 81 textboxes that I need to convert to/from a char array, while i could write out all the conversions I'd rather learn how to dynamically handle all of the textBox inputs.

Current Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sudoku = new char[,]
    {
        { '5', '3', '.', '.', '7', '.', '.', '.', '.' },
        { '6', '.', '.', '1', '9', '5', '.', '.', '.' },
        { '.', '9', '8', '.', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.' },
        { '8', '.', '.', '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '3' },
        { '4', '.', '.', '8', '.', '3', '.', '.', '1' },
        { '7', '.', '.', '.', '2', '.', '.', '.', '6' },
        { '.', '6', '.', '.', '.', '.', '2', '8', '.' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '4', '1', '9', '.', '.', '5' },
        { '.', '.', '.', '.', '8', '.', '.', '7', '9' }
    };

    sudoku[0, 0] = toChar(textBox1);
    solveSudoku(sudoku);
}

public char toChar(TextBox tb)
{
    string[] nopes = { "0", "" };
    if (nopes.Contains<String>(tb.Text))
    {
        tb.Text = ".";
    }
    char val = Convert.ToChar(tb.Text);
    return val;
}
```

I want to be able to loop through every textbox and it's value to an ordered pair.

Kinda like this:
**PSUEDO CODE**

```
int i = 1;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls)
{
    sudoku[x, y] = tb + i.text
    x++; i++;
    if (x == 9)
    {
        y = 1; x = 0;
    }
}
```

I've tried a few different solutions i've found here, but i was unable to get them to work how i want.

Comment: I would still consider using a DataGridView, at least in Winforms.

Comment: In your pseudo-code you loop through a `Controls` collection to access the `TextBox` controls.  Have you tried that?  Did it fail in some way?  It's not clear what `tb + i.text` is meant to accomplish.  But if you group your `TextBox` controls in a parent container control then what stops you from looping through them?

Comment: For tb + i.text i need the "i" to represent each textbox number (1-81)
I need the text element of each textbox.

textBox(1-81).text

Comment: The error i got when attempting it the first time was an error stating i cannot convert a progress bar to a TextBox. Which didn't make sense to me as i was asking foreach TextBox tb in this.Controls

Comment: You are asking for every control in the Controls collection, not just the TextBoxes.  Add a filter:  `TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();`

Comment: That is not the way to write it. Use `var boxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();` - But that alone will not really get the correct order..

Comment: When I show boxes.Count.ToString() i get a return of 0

Comment: Looks like it's not detecting a TextBox in any of my Controls.
Since that's happening, i do have all of these textboxes in a GroupBox could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Nope, looks like that didn't change it either tried:

```var boxes = groupBox1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
            MessageBox.Show(boxes.Count.ToString());
```
Which returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

Both LarsTech and TaW had the answers, my issue was my TextBoxes were nested in other controls. GroupBox then LayoutFlowPanel making it hard to access.

To resolve this i removed everything from the GroupBox and used this:

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
            {
                //if (tb is TextBox)
                //{
                    MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
                    sudoku[x, y] = toChar(tb);
                    x++; i++;
                    if (x == 9)
                    {
                        y++; x = 0;
                    }
                //}
                
            }
```